# Does default parameterizing in C++ functions push the default values onto stack?

Tags: c++, c++11

If a function has 20 parameters (pointers)(4 used in the example) with default values for all of them pointed to NULL, does that that mean each call to this function does a PUSH to stack a NULL value during runtime?

A sample such function might look like:

```
function test(val1=NULL, val2=NULL, .... val20=NULL)
```

I am asking this to maximize speed and by reducing # cycles during the function calls.

## TEST CASE (THERE ARE SOME EXTRA THINGS IN HERE AS WELL)

```
// ArgsListTest.cpp
// @author Mathew Kurian

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

// Look at the difference in psuedo-assembly code
// My knowledge in compiler is little, but I can see that
// that there are unncessary cycles being wasted for this part.

// **** With array (this example) *****
// LOAD         Reg, memAddressOfArray
// WRITETOMEM   Reg, ptrToVar1
// INCREMENT    sp
// WRITETOMEM   Reg, ptrToVar2
// DECREMENT    sp
// PUSH         ptrToArray
// JUMP         test

//  ***** IDEALLY SUPPOSED TO LIKE THIS *****
// PUSH        ptrToVar2
// PUSH        ptrToVar1
// JUMP        test

class Base
{
public:
    virtual int test(void* arguments[])
    {
        cout << "Base function being called. VTable lookup ignored since there is no virtual." << endl;
        cout << *static_cast<int*>(arguments[0]) << endl;   // Parameter 1 (Thinks there is only 1 parameter!)

        int x = 5;      x += 1; // Random math to prevent optimizations. (I hope)
        return x;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int test(void* arguments[])
    {
        // cout << "Derived function being called. VTable lookup during runtime. Slight overhead here!" << endl;

        // cout << *static_cast<string*>(arguments[0]) << endl; // Parameter 1
        // cout << *static_cast<int*>(arguments[1]) << endl;   // Parameter 2

        int x = 5;      x += 1;
        return x;
    }
};

class Base2
{
public:
    virtual int test(void* arg1 = NULL, void* arg2 = NULL, void* arg3 = NULL, void* arg4 = NULL)
    {
        // cout << "Base2 function being called. VTable lookup ignored since there is no virtual." << endl;

        // cout << *static_cast<string*>(arg1) << endl; // Parameter 1
        // cout << *static_cast<int*>(arg2) << endl;   // Parameter 2
        int x = 5;      x += 1;
        return x;
    }

    virtual int test2()
    {
        int x = 5;      x += 1;
        return x;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Base * base = new Derived;
    Base2 * base2 = new Base2;

    int r = 0;
    string * str = new string("sunny");
    int * vale = new int(20);
    int iterations = 1000000000;

    //================================================================================

    printf("Using No-Parameters [%d iterations]\n", iterations);

    clock_t tStart = clock();

    for (int x = 0; x < iterations; x++)
    {
        r = base2->test2();
    }

    printf("Time taken: %.9fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    //================================================================================

    printf("Using Array [%d iterations]\n", iterations);

    tStart = clock();

    for (int x = 0; x < iterations; x++)
    {
        void * arguments[] = { str, vale };
        r = base->test(arguments);
    }

    printf("Time taken: %.9fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    //================================================================================

    printf("Using Default-Parameters [%d iterations]\n", iterations);

    tStart = clock();

    for (int x = 0; x < iterations; x++)
    {
        r = base2->test(str, vale);
    }

    printf("Time taken: %.9fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    //================================================================================

    // cout << "NOTE: Derived class has no extra methods although the parameter counts are different.\n      Parent class doesn't even realize parameter 1 exists!" << endl;

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

## OUTPUT (WHICH DOESNT MAKE LOGICAL SENSE)

[image]

## Why is the first test slower than the second? And how creating an array is actually faster than just `PUSH NULL`?

Comment: The standard does not say it, and it's an implementation detail. But most of the time yes. The calling convention should be honored, unless the function is in-lined during compilation.

Comment: If you really have 20 arguments, you might want to consider a narrower interface, or passing a reference to a `struct` around.

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: Functions with 20 arguments are the crazy uncle of the root of all evil.

Comment: Nothing prevents the compiler (or programmer, for this matter) from actually producing overloaded versions of the function sans default parameters, with actual default values substituted as local vars inside the overloaded variants.

Comment: I have updated the question with a sample case and my performance results, which are confusing me.

Comment: 1. Do you use optimisation? 2. Do you repeat your measurements? 3. The program repeats the exactly same iterations, do you understand that this is "dangerous" because compiler can try to optimise this?

Comment: @kim123 1. `Disabled (/Od)` 2. What do you mean? 3. Even if optimizations are disabled?

Comment: you are trying to optimize your code without optimization enabled. what is the point of it?

Comment: @Bryan Chen What do you mean? I have disabled optimizations for testing purposes only. I want to get the raw speed. With optimizations disabled, logically speaking, the first result should be the fastest (because there are no parameters), followed by the default parameterizing (because it is only push and pops), and finally the array (which has to write/increment/decrement and push + pop). So, something doesn't add up here. Or I am an idiot (which is a good possibility)

Comment: making your code run faster in debug build is meaningless. it does no mean your code run faster in release build

Comment: @Bryan Chen I agree with you but this is for proof of concept honestly. I am just trying to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the virtual methods are impacting your results. I copied your methods to the global scope which demonstrated a different performance order.

```
Using No-Parameters [1000000000 iterations]
Time taken: 24.831000000s
Using Array [1000000000 iterations]
Time taken: 24.730000000s
Using Default-Parameters [1000000000 iterations]
Time taken: 25.241000000s
Using No-Parameters [1000000000 iterations] on int testA()
Time taken: 21.664000000s
Using Array [1000000000 iterations] on int testB(void* arguments[])
Time taken: 22.384000000s
Using Default-Parameters [1000000000 iterations] int testC(void* arg1 = NULL, ...)
Time taken: 22.329000000s
```

EDIT:

Same test with the array assignment in testB moved outside the scope of the for loop:

```
Using No-Parameters [1000000000 iterations]
Time taken: 24.713000000s
Using Array [1000000000 iterations]
Time taken: 24.686000000s
Using Default-Parameters [1000000000 iterations]
Time taken: 25.225000000s
Using No-Parameters [1000000000 iterations] on int testA()
Time taken: 21.653000000s
Using Array [1000000000 iterations] on int testB(void* arguments[])
Time taken: 21.896000000s
Using Default-Parameters [1000000000 iterations] int testC(void* arg1 = NULL, ...)
Time taken: 22.353000000s
```

Comment: Removing the array assignment outside of the for loop in testB yielded the following order with testA being the fastest: testA, testB, testC. So without any further investigation, it seems the argument count is affecting performance in a consistent manner.

Comment: BTW, testA, testB, & testC are the respective copies of the original methods tested and displayed on the op's output; thus, the six tests.

Comment: @mk1 They're your 3 methods/functions copied and pasted just above your "class Base" definition, but without the virtual keyword. Unlike C# and Java, you can create "global" functions in C/C++ that don't live within a class definition.

Comment: Thank you. PS your computer is fast!

Comment: Thanks. Precision M6700, 32GB, Quadro K5000M. I highly recommend the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps. The other simple solution is to have multiple entry points:

```
  # Pseudocode
  PUSH nullptr # Default argument 20
  PUSH nullptr # Default argument 19
  PUSH nullptr # Default argument 18
  ...
  ENTRYPOINT(test)
```

If you have N default arguments, you jump to an address N instructions in front of the regular entrypoint. Benefit: the code to push these default arguments can now be shared amongst callers. Requires a bit of linker smartness, though.

Comment: Can you please expand on this? Would something like this be embedded in the C++ code itself?

Comment: @mk1: It's pseudo-assembly code, showing how a compiler can generate an alternative implementation for a C++ function with default arguments. You were wondering if each caller would push default arguments; this example shows that the pushing can also be done by an optional prolog to the called function.